# Vim Mapping Access Register Content

Tags: vim

I want to write a mapping that makes i possible to use a macro call as in normal mode for the visual line mode. So select somethin and type `@<register>`. So far I've to open the command line and execute a normal command on the selection `:'<,'>norm @<resgister>`. Cause the `<register>` should be flexible and I don't want to define a mapping for each register name (whats wrong in so many perspectives), my current approach is to use a `<expr>` mapping combined with a `getChar()` function call. This is how my current draft looks like:

```
vnoremap <expr> @ "=nr2char(getchar())<cr>:'<,'> norm @=<CR>
```

I know that the `@=` can't work here. In the `=` register is now stored the name of the actual register, the user typed after the `@` this mapping is for. How can I work with the `<expr>` now, so that the correct macro stored in the given register is executed on the whole selection?
I guess have to work with `v:register` or `getreg()`, but I don't know how to.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the expression mapping, you don't need to go through the expression register. Instead, you can simply return the Ex command that would invoke your macro on the selected lines, and concatenate the query into it:

```
:xnoremap <expr> @ ":norm @" . nr2char(getchar()) . "<CR>"
```

- For a visual mode mapping, the `:` command will automatically insert the `'<,'>` range.
- `:vmap` is for both visual and select mode. Printable characters (like your `@` left-hand side) should override in select mode. Therefore, use `:xmap`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!